# How to disable ajax when IE8 is detected?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am facing a serious issue that everytime I click save/cancel button, IE8(while firefox and chrome worked fine) will freeze. Once I disable the js on my browser, it than worked fine. I suspected it might because of some ajax call bound to the button, so is it possible to disable ajax in my code when an IE browser is detect?

Comment: You could, but you should rather try to find the exact problem, instead of doing this. By the way, the simplest hack would be redefining your ajax function with NOP.

Comment: 1. Check F12 , 2. Find error , 3. Fix it

Comment: @SergeS the problem is due the browser crashes, I can't see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition code on your JavaScript code to ignore browser is IE,

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8.")!=-1){
     // ajax code
}
```

Another way use HTML conditionals

```
<!--[if IE 8]> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
          // ajax code
     </script> 
< ![endif]-->
```